# In php, search a MySQL database using input from different form elements

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a web app that currently returns MySQL records based on 1 input search (city).
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZ1c3.png)

However, when i add a 2nd input to search such as 'plowtruck'  the results are 2 tables (note that the **search is being done in the same table** where both input criteria are 2 columns in the table):
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73spV.png)

I want to return only the 2nd table which includes the query for both input criteria.

I believe the problem is how I'm using conditionals for the search:

```
if(empty($_POST["City"]))                          
{
echo "a city is required!";
}else if(mysqli_num_rows($cityResults) > 0)     
{
//return results using mysqli_fetch
}
else if(!(mysqli_num_rows($cityResults)))                        
        {
            //nothing found
        }
if(mysqli_num_rows($CityPlowTruckResults) > 0)
{
//return more results using mysqli_fetch
}
```

QUERIES:

```
//SQL queries
        $queryCity = "SELECT LName, FName, Phone, AreaSize, PlowTruck, Street, City, Zip, Stat, RequestID, RequestDate, RequestTime
                            FROM requests
                            WHERE City='$city'
                            AND Stat ='pending' ";

        $queryCityPlowTruck = "SELECT LName, FName, Phone, AreaSize, PlowTruck, Street, City, Zip, Stat, RequestID, RequestDate, RequestTime
                                     FROM requests
                                     WHERE City='$city'
                                     AND PlowTruck = '$plowtruck'
                                     AND Stat ='pending' ";
```

I'm not sure how to solve this problem, does anyone know.

Front-end seach form looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EW3A4.png)

Front-end html code(last part pertaining to question):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36z86.png)

My PHP code is (pt.1): 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnZqA.png)

My PHP code is (pt.2): 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6dRm.png)

My PHP code is (pt.3): 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Su29.png)

My database schema: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAE7p.png)

Comment: How about a JOIN?

Comment: the search is being done in only 1 table, i don't think i need a join

Comment: Then your question appears to be not quite clear.

Comment: I've edited to be more clear

Comment: Then you need a query which accepts both search criteria.

Comment: can you please show the query? @JayBlanchard is correct and that's where your answer lays

Comment: I want the result to be the 2nd file i've upload (which is output of both queries). But is displaying 1 result (as a table) followed by another result (another table, i.e. the table i want to display)

Comment: I wonder if you realise that the files you've uploaded show results, and I'm asking how your query is built so I can help you.

Comment: i've posted the queries.  If the user chooses query based on city only, the 1st result should be shown... if the user search based on city & plowtruck i want the 2nd result to be show, but is showing both results.. so that's why I think the problem is with conditionals..

Comment: @codEinstein I've made an answer that I believe may aid you, it is a logical matter

Comment: thank you. I didnt know you could pass php variables into sql queries..

Comment: @codEinstein You can with ***great*** caution. Beware of _SQL Injection_...

Answer (score 0):

Both queries are exactly the same, the only variance is a 'where' condition that you've got. This is a matter of logic - what you are doing is:

1. If I don't receive a city, echo it out. If my $cityResults has results, show them, if not, don't.
2. If my $CityPlowTruckResults has results, show them.

You're executing both queries before the if statements, and your last if is going to do whatever code you've got in it because it recognizes it has results.

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($CityPlowTruckResults) > 0)
{
    //return more results using mysqli_fetch
    //This is incorrect, this is another query, a different one, this is fetching $CityPlowTruckResults
    //which is different from $cityResults query. They are independente and you're probably returning both
}
```

Consider doing this to make it simple - Remove the last if statement and combine the queries as such:

```
$extraWhere = "";
if (empty($plowtruck)) {
    $extraWhere = "AND PlowTruck = '$plowtruck'";
}
$queryCity = "SELECT LName, FName, Phone, AreaSize, PlowTruck, Street, City, Zip, Stat, RequestID, RequestDate, RequestTime
                            FROM requests
                            WHERE City='$city'
                            $extraWhere 
                            AND Stat ='pending'";
// ... execute the query ...
if(empty($_POST["City"])) {
    echo "a city is required!";
}else { 
    if(mysqli_num_rows($cityResults) > 0) {
        //return results using mysqli_fetch
    }
    else  {
       //do nothing
    }
}
```

About the code itself, there are better and safer ways to handle queries and such, but if you intend to return 1 single result (and not two query results), you need to either combine them into one query (like I did, "poorly" I may add) or use a JOIN statement to combine both queries.

EDIT: 
After seeing your new screenshots, it has become clear that your variable $plowTruck always has a value (it can be 'yes', 'no', 'choice').

You can work it by doing:

```
$extraWhere = "";
if ($plowtruck != 'choice') {
    $extraWhere = "AND PlowTruck = '$plowtruck'";
}
```

However, it is very important to note that your code is unsafe (VERY carefull with SqlInjection) as you're taking direct input from your $_POST variables.

Comment: did it help? @codEinstein

Comment: i must clarify that "cityResults" is not the actual string query, but the query with results such as $cityResults = mysqli_query($db_connection, $queryCity);  the string query is queryCity

Comment: @codEinstein my bad, updated. What I meant is that queryCity is queryCityPlowTruck become one (so you can use the same query to have more or less results, depending if extraWhere is an AND or OR) and removing the extra if as I believe - I may be wrong by lack of deph in what is actually written in your code - it is definitly a logical error. It could also be that you're making 2 requests? It really depends on how you're handling it. Let me know if you can fix it

Comment: if you're saying only city  does not work (query works works just fine, extraWhere is either empty or has an extra part of text), then it's probably the isset($plowtruck). Try if empty($plowtruck). Updated my answer. It's not 'not flexible', it's just sloppy logic.

Comment: it works for some cases and not for others... for instance, it does not work when user chooses a city only (with no choice of plowtruck),, but it works when user chooses a city and "yes". I try replace AND with OR on the query but it works again for some cases and not for others.. I think your answer is not flexible..

Comment: no need, just update the post with screenshots of it and I'll re-write this answer accordingly

Comment: i uploaded the snapshots, but says it'll be peer reviewed before appear to the public

Comment: @codEinstein updated the answer, check the edit in the end of my answer

Comment: Did you? It looks same to me... Testing: picking city 'Providence' AND (no choice of plowtruck) is not working (should return 3, it's returning nothing). Also picking city 'Providence' AND plowtruck=no is not working (should return 1, returns 0)... Do you know how can i fix this?

Comment: have you changed "isset" to != "choice"? Please write var_dump($extraWhere). This is a logic error, the query is fine, what is giving wrong answers is the $extraWhere because of the if statement that compares what is in $plowtruck

Comment: yes, it plowtruck as different options from which the search is based upon. After changing the code on your last edit it finally works. Thank you.

Comment: Glad you got it working! Feel free to edit my answer with what you think is appropriate or to even mark it as a solution